# R* Tree work with dynamic data

Tags: c++, algorithms

I'm searching an algorithm to store my data (which are moving objects' coordinates) and allow me to query objects within a specific radius of a specific point.

I came up with R* Tree which is said as good solution for geographical data, but as I studied further, R* Tree stored data in secondary memory and its data mostly don't change over time.

But my data is updated per second, so if I implement R* Tree, the insert and delete part of the algorithm will be called many time.

Is R* tree is suitable for my case or not? If it isn't, can anyone suggest me a better algorithm?

Comment: I'm more familiar with regular R-trees and Hilbert R-trees, but I couldn't find anything indicating it's tied to secondary memory (whatever you mean by that) or that insertion/deletion isn't efficient. Could you elaborate why you think that?

Comment: @delnan I used the term secondary memory (like a hard disk) as in this answer http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/96518/115995. And my point here that my data is changed so fast (updated per second per object), so with all delete and insert that I have to call in order to update the data, it is like rebuild a new tree

Comment: A tree working being designed for secondary memory is generally a *good* thing even if your workload fits into RAM, because the same techniques that minimize disk reads also minimize cache misses. And adding/updating/deleting m nodes where m < n should be more efficient than rebuilding the whole tree of n nodes with the new values.